# Update only values from an <col>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I really need to know if it's possible to update the values under a specific column on a table.

```
<table>
    <col with="auto">
    <col with="auto">
    <col with="auto" id="update_me">

<?php
for(hundreds of lines){
?>
    <tr>
    <td>something 0</td>
    <td>something 1</td>
    <td>Need to update</td>
    <tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

I will be using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#update_me").load("response.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$("#update_me").load('response.php');
}, 6000);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

The php will only generate the values from the specific column!

Comment: It is indeed possible to do this - look into the [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) or [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selectors for each tr in your table, depending on how you format your response.

Comment: Would you like to give me an example? It seems not very easy... I just wanna update the third column, but how do I refer to that?

Comment: `<col>` is pretty useless. Most useful attributes aren't cast to the `<td>`s under the `<col>`. If you want to update 1 column in all rows, it will require more imaginative javascript than using `<col>`s. Sorry =) **edit** It also depends on the format of your response. Is it 1 column in HTML? That's bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $.getJSON('response.php', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
               $('#value'+index).html(value).show();
        });
      });       
      }, 3000);
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, this is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more what you are looking for:

```
My Table
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="auto"> </td>
    <td width="auto"> </td>
    <td width="auto" id="update_me1"></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td width="auto"> </td>
    <td width="auto"> </td>
    <td width="auto" id="update_me2"></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td width="auto"> </td>
    <td width="auto"> </td>
    <td width="auto" id="update_me3"></td>
<tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#update_me").load("response.php");
    var arr = ['1','2','3'];

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $.each(arr, function() {
          $('#update_me' + this).load('response.php');  
        });
    }, 6000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** This javascript calls the response.php multiple times. So for each ID in `arr` it will call the script. If you pass the ID to the script (as described in my comments below), you can limit the data returned by each request:

$('#update_me' + this).load('response.php?id' + this);

This means that for each iteration of `arr`, you will be calling response with the appropriate id:

```
'#update_me1' is populated with the results from 'response.php?id=1'
'#update_me2' is populated with the results from 'response.php?id=2'
'#update_me3' is populated with the results from 'response.php?id=3'
etc...
```

Otherwise, you need to call response.php once and parse the data in the javascript. Those are the only options you have.

Comment: I get it... but, can I use the same id on hundreds of table data (<td>)? It is correct under w3c?

Comment: I don't think it will work! It's putting all the values under the first <td id="values"> (that gets generated by my index.php). So at the first time values are loaded from php script and works ok, but the jquery script puts the values from response.php under the first <td> and the rest of the <td>s remain as they were generated the first time...

Comment: Each ID should be unique according the CSS specification. You may need to try implementing a class for each TD that you can use instead. I see what you asking now. I will work on an update.

Comment: Thank a lot... I will see what i can do with my programming skills :)

Comment: With class will put the same value on all <td class="value"> doesn't work either...

Comment: Not solved. The requested data will be a block of data I will have to break it apart and place it under the right <td> generating the id name it's very easy can do it like <td id="value<?php echo $i?>"> considering a for block in php which $i will be an iterator. So the jquery script will load the block of data generated by response.php after that jquery will have to break it appart and place it under the proper <td> that will be a more difficult move...

Comment: Just send it to the response.php file. So in the jquery while you are looping through the IDs, add it to the load function call. `$('#update_me' + this).load('response.php?id=' + this);` and have the php file load the portion you are requesting.

Comment: Lets see if I understood, the response.php is going to echo the result of a query wich I will split by an added plus (+) ex returned value from php script: 12+23+45+67+8+9+90+... the php script will be executed only once not more. So I want to store the returned value in a javascript variable and than split it by the added + and place it at each <td> so I think that will not work either.

Comment: Each request will pass a unique id `request.php?id=1`, `request.php?id=2`, etc. You cannot have it both ways. You either need to: 1) Call the script once, get all of the data and split the data out in the javascript or 2) call the script multiple times passing the ID to the script getting just the results for each column. Which is it? I'm not sure what you expectation is. You cannot expect the data to appear magically.

Comment: I understand, I want to execute the script only once than store it,  split it and place it on the <td> I made some tryes but not sucess yet! :) Thank you very much... jquery script:<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    //armazena a o resutado do script php
       jQuery.get('response.php', function ( data ) {
     var tData = data.split("+");
     var i=-1,limit=tData.length;
     while(++i<limit){
      $(tData[i]).appendTo('#value'.i);
     }
   });
   }, 6000);    
       $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   });
   </script>

Comment: Doesn't anyone on this site know how to spell "width"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why nobody has suggested

```
jQuery("td:nth-child(" + column_number + ")").each(function(row_number)
{ 
    //Do something to this row's cell in column "column_number" 
});
```

Comment: It does seem to work either because I don't know how many rows I will have (they will be generated by php script), and still a problem the first row it is a description (no need to update)...

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$.get('response.php', function(data) {
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
$('#value'+index).html(value).show();
});
});
}, 3000);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
});
</script>

Comment: This should be working just fine but is printing " and , and the values as well... what is wrong? The php array is json_encoded and plain text: header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($array);

Comment: @FCC-PT jQuery doesn't need browser support for its selectors to work. it doesn't need to know how many rows there are only needs to know which column you want to update. You can remove the first row out of the selectors with a `.not()` can we see a small example of the json that you are using?

Comment: It's working PERFECT<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $.getJSON('response.php', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
               $('#value'+index).html(value).show();
        });
      });       
      }, 3000);
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
   });
</script>